# How to generate a repeated code with simple function?

Tags: r

How to generate this code without repeating it each time?

I have data with 6 columns, where I want to eliminate 0 if it exists in each column and then take the average.

```
mean(grade$Q1[grade$Q1>0])
mean(grade$Q2[grade$Q2>0])
mean(grade$Q2[grade$Q3>0])
mean(grade$Q2[grade$Q4>0])
mean(grade$Q2[grade$Q5>0])
mean(grade$Q2[grade$Q6>0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and custom argument `fun`

```
dta <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,1,2), y=c(0,1,2,3))
apply(dta, 2, function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
```

Result

```
  x   y 
1.5 2.0
```

Comment: so in my situation I need to but x=c(grade$Q1, grade$Q2, grade$Q3, grade$Q4, grade$Q5,  grade$Q6) and this will work.

Comment: @RAMIE:  If you have the special case where your dataset has no other columns except `Q1` through `Q6`, then you can do just `sapply(grade, function(x) mean(x[x>0]))`.  If your data.frame has other columns, then you would want the code to be `apply(grade[ , paste0("Q", 1:6)], 2, function(x) mean(x[x>0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write your own custom function and then call it for one column of a dataframe at a time, or for a group of columns.  This can be used on different dataframes.  Here's some code:

```
# example dataset
set.seed(1234)
grade <- data.frame(
    Q1 = sample(runif(n=100, min=-10, max=100)),
    Q2 = sample(runif(n=100, min=-10, max=100)),
    Q3 = sample(runif(n=100, min=-10, max=100)),
    Q4 = sample(runif(n=100, min=-10, max=100)),
    Q5 = sample(runif(n=100, min=-10, max=100)),
    Q6 = sample(runif(n=100, min=-10, max=100))
)

# custom function
myfun <- function(df, col, threshold) {
    df <- get(df)
    vec <- df[[col]]
    mean(vec[vec>threshold])
}

# test the function
myfun(df="grade", col="Q1", threshold=0)
    #> 43.48234    

# compare function output to "manual" output
mean(grade$Q1[grade$Q1>0])
    #> 43.48234

# apply the function to many columns
mapply(myfun, c("Q1", "Q2"), MoreArgs=list(df="grade", threshold=0))
    #>       Q1        Q2 
    #> 43.48234  49.01906
```

Comment: is there any standard function like a loop or something that we can use instead of using custom function.